# cannot configure or make install samtools 0.1.19

Tags: make, configure

I need to install a certain version of samtools (0.1.19) (found at https://sourceforge.net/projects/samtools/).

./configure returns "no such file..."
make works correctly (from what I can tell)
sudo make install returns "make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop."

Different versions work fine. I'm completely lost, the readme doesn't provide any help and I am not savvy enough to detect any problems in the makefile. Any help would be greatly appreciated after hours of failed attempts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really you do not need to compile this application by yourself.

It [is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=samtools&searchon=names) in all currently supported versions in *universe* pocket.
You can add this pocket with (if it is no enabled) the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

and then you can simply install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install samtools
```

---

If you really want to compile `samtools`, then you do not need to run `./configure` script (as it does not exist), just use `make`:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://vorboss.dl.sourceforge.net/project/samtools/samtools/0.1.19/samtools-0.1.19.tar.bz2
tar -xf samtools-0.1.19.tar.bz2
cd samtools-0.1.19
make
```

and you will get:

> ```
> $ ./samtools 
>
> Program: samtools (Tools for alignments in the SAM format)
> Version: 0.1.19-44428cd
>
> Usage:   samtools <command> [options]
>
> Command: view        SAM<->BAM conversion
>          sort        sort alignment file
>          mpileup     multi-way pileup
>          depth       compute the depth
>          faidx       index/extract FASTA
>          tview       text alignment viewer
>          index       index alignment
>          idxstats    BAM index stats (r595 or later)
>          fixmate     fix mate information
>          flagstat    simple stats
>          calmd       recalculate MD/NM tags and '=' bases
>          merge       merge sorted alignments
>          rmdup       remove PCR duplicates
>          reheader    replace BAM header
>          cat         concatenate BAMs
>          bedcov      read depth per BED region
>          targetcut   cut fosmid regions (for fosmid pool only)
>          phase       phase heterozygotes
>          bamshuf     shuffle and group alignments by name
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to install the previous version: sudo apt-get install samtools=0.1.19
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '0.1.19' for 'samtools' was not found

Comment: Also, 'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.1.

Comment: 18.04 has [samtools (1.7-1)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/samtools). So if you really want 0.1.19, then compile it as described in my answer. I have never used this software, but it is possible that 1.7-1 may replace 0.1.19 by all functionality.